# Unable to connect salesforce from a podman Jenkins container

Tags: jenkins, salesforce, podman

I have podman Jenkins container. I am trying to integrate Jenkins with salesforce following official site documentation. The process worked well for dockerised Jenkins container. However, for podman container I always have below error:

**Error (1): We encountered a JSON web token error, which is likely not an issue with Salesforce CLI. Here’s the error: Error authenticating with JWT.
Errors encountered:
request to https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN login.salesforce.com**

I thought it was a network/proxy error. I tried podman container with and without network. Both ways didn't worked. Proxy is configured very well. As per the error it should be some issue with my cert files but the same volume worked well for dockerised Jenkins. I ensured that server.key file was uploaded in Jenkins and respective server.crt file was uploaded in connected app and even verified if I used a valid consumer key. Still no luck with podman Jenkins container.

Though error appears to be network/proxy related, the same volume for a dockerised Jenkins should throw some error but unexpectedly it worked well. I am sure that integrating salesforce and jenkins might not be related to whether I use Jenkins as docker container or podman container however there might be chance that I would have missed some other needed steps.

Please help me and suggest some other alternatives.

Thanks in advance